# Angular form with file uploader submit event does not work

Tags: angular, file-upload

I have a simple angular 9 front end application which has a file uploader as below in my `fileuploader.component.html`

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div>
  <input type="file" name="finput">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button  type="submit" >Upload File</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And,in my `fileuploader.component.ts` I have implemented the `onSubmit()` method,

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log('in on submit');
    // -- submit logic here----
  }
```

However, my `onSubmit()` method does not get called and I get below warning on PhpStorm in `fileuploader.component.html`.

```
Event ngSubmit is not emitted by any applicable directives nor by form element
```

Any idea on what the problem is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the `submit` event.

```html
<form (submit)="onSubmit()">
</form>
```